# How to template a function to take arbitrary functions or methods as parameter

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, variadic-templates

I'd like to write a function which can both take a function or a method as parameter. ie a function accepting the same parameter than the `std::thread` constructor.

So far I have something working for a function but have hard time for methods:

```
template<typename F, typename... Args>
typename std::result_of<typename std::decay<F>::type(typename std::decay<Args>::type...)>::type
call(F &&func, Args... args) {
    return func(args...);
}

void hello() { std::cout << "hello\n"; }

class Hello {
public:
    Hello() = default;
    ~Hello() = default;
    void hello() { std::cout << "hello\n"; }
};

int main()
{
    // func
    call(hello);

    // meth
    Hello h;
    call(&Hello::hello, &h);
}
```

I tried to reproduce what is done by the contructor of `std::thread` but struggle to find the right way to write it.

Comment: You could just wrap any methods into a lambda expression instead. It might be much easier.

Comment: You want to look up std::invoke. If you cannot use it, you probably need to write an overload for member function pointers.

Comment: @n. 'pronouns' m. Yes i saw https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/invoke but i'm stuck to c++14. How would you write an overload for member function pointers ? It's basically what i fail to do '^^

Comment: Basically what you want is [`std::invoke`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/invoke), but that requires C++17.

Comment: template<typename F, typename... Args>
auto call(F &&func, Args&&... args) -> decltype(std::ref(func)(std::forward<Args>(args)...)) {
    return std::ref(func)(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
} do the trick for it worth.

Comment: You can try and copy a possible implementation from here https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/invoke

Comment: Thank you "n. 'pronouns' m"